# Is the "size" of fundamental particles invariant under Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, elementary-particles

I was reading [this paper](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=hpa-001:1956:29::960) about invariance of quantum-mechanical equations in relativistic conditions.

Although I couldn't understand most of it, I was curious to know if the "size" of fundamental particles is also invariant under Special Relativity?

What I mean to ask is this: A particle probability distribution is a four dimensional plot with x, y, z and probability as the axes. Are the distance axes, that is the x, y and z axes, invariant under special relativity?

If so, why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78771/discussion-on-question-by-ritesh-singh-is-the-size-of-fundamental-particles-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental particles of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) are point particles with the quantum numbers given in the table, and a fixed mass given in the table.The definition of a point is invariant to Lorenz transformations, it has a size of zero dimensions.

In special relativity mass is the "length" of [the four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) describing the particle $(E,p_x.p_y,p_z)$, that is why it is called the invariant mass, because it is invariant under Lorenz transformations.

Now if you are trying to discuss about the mass in the [$E=mc^2$](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html) famous formula, the effective inertial mass of a moving object or particle, the elementary particles obey it , as they obey all Lorentz transformation rules. It  is not a useful concept for experiments in particle physics as they can be mathematically cleanly modeled with the four vector formulae, and all calculations(scattering crossections etc) follow Lorentz invariance rules.

Edit after question edit:

> What I mean to ask is this: A particle probability distribution is a four dimensional plot with x, y, z and probability as the axes. Are the distance axes, that is the x, y and z axes, invariant under special relativity?

The axes by mathematical definition are invariant, the same as the points defining the size of particles  in the elementary particle table. The solutions of relativistic quantum mechanical equations are covariant to the Lorenz transformations, i.e. the total crossections for interactions are independent of the velocity of the center of mass system , by mathematical construction. (Note that crossections , which are what can be measured, are proportional to the probability of interaction.)

The [differential  crossections](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/quantum-physics/how-to-translate-cross-sections-between-center-of-mass-and-lab-frames/)  , for example angular distributions, will change  according to the Lorenz boost , for example from center of mass to laboratory frame.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/221468)

Comment: I agree with stafusa - this isn't an answer to the question as posed.

Comment: @stafusa the answer was drastically edited after I answered it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  the answer was drastically edited after I answered i

Comment: @annav I had thought about that and checked the earlier versions of the question: don't they all ask about "*size*" instead of mass?

Comment: @stafusa the size is answered in the first sentence, and then I clarify what is invariant   under special relativity. I thought the OP was confused with the growth of mass due to the relativistic mass formula, thinking it as growth of size. Actually the editing confuses the issue further. One would have to go into field theory and relativistic invariance of wave packets , and their spread and do not feel up to it,

Comment: Ok, @annav, I guess the extent of the answer dedicated to the mass misled some of us. Also, it's left to the reader to figure out that a size of $0$ (zero) remains unchanged.

Comment: @annav Thanks for your answer. Do the axes of the probability distribution go through length contraction at relativistic speeds of the particle?